# Flash doesn't work with chromium on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, flash, ubuntu, plugins, chromium

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash after install of flashplugin-installer package flash should work in chromium, but mine doesn't.
It installed libflashplayer.so into /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer and firefox works perfectly with it. However, chromium doesn't see this plugin. chrome://plugins/ show nothing. 
If i run "chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so" it see plugin, but on page with flash it says "Could not play".

libflashplayer.so: 11.2.202.626
chromium: Version 50.0.2661.102 Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

All you need is to install adobe-flashplugin instead of flashplugin-installer. With it chromium can play flash.